# Passing formatted HTML code from SQL database to HTML page

Tags: php, html, sql

I have an SQL database that is passing data to an HTML page using this method [Link Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3?hl=ja):

```
downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
  var xml = data.responseXML;
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
    var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: point,
      icon: icon.icon,
      shadow: icon.shadow
    });
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
  }`enter code here`
});
```

Editing the HTML in this part is fine but if I were to pass Formatted HTML e.g. `<b> Hello World </b>` to this as a variable, it would display as "`<b> Hello World </b>`" and so would not be taken as HTML code.

I want do this so I can pass preformatted HTML to the InfoWindow.

Is their a way round this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, instead of using the following in the PHP file to create the XML:

```
// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}
```

I used DOM XML functions:

```
// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  $node = $doc->create_element("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->append_child($node);

  $newnode->set_attribute("name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->set_attribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->set_attribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->set_attribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->set_attribute("type", $row['type']);
}
```

Both versions are shown [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3?hl=ja)